# Erlang receive ***WARNING***

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a process that sits in a loop and receives commands.

```
receive
    increase ->
        ...
    decrease ->
        ...
    after 5000 ->
        ...
end
```

But when I bombard it with thousands of messages it breaks down and receives these warnings.

Warning Message:

```
***WARNING*** Unexp msg {<0.106.0>,rec_acked}, info {running,
                                                     [{'_UserConnections',20}],
                                                     {ieval,3994,34,log,
                                                      clientLogging,
                                                      [20],
                                                      false}}
```

Is there anyway to handle this?  And does it cause any issue?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Can you try creating a reduced test case to trigger this warning? This is the only instance I could find of this exact warning: https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/770454f0a32fbc0714c6762ed3e4d761b799814f/lib/debugger/src/dbg_icmd.erl#L225-L226. Not sure why that process is receiving that `rec_acked` message.

Comment: It happens if around 1000+ processes send a message to 1 PID (the loop).

Comment: There has to be some additional condition triggering this. I just sent 2000 messages to a single process from 2000 spawned process and there was no warning message (total 4 million messages). The Erlang VM is currently using 500MB+ of RAM because the main process hasn't processed any message.

Comment: What version are you using?  I am using 18.3 (due to libraries that require this version)

Comment: @Dogbert this is only showing when in debug.

Comment: I tested on 20.0. By "in debug" you mean the Debugger was running (the `debugger` module)?

Comment: Yes for intellij

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is good just for example and practice, but don't run in production environment.
You should always receive all messages from process mailbox and select what you want after getting.

```
handle_message() ->
    receive
        Msg ->
            handle_message(Msg)
    after 5000 ->
            handle_timeout()
    end.

handle_message(increase) ->
    ...;
handle_message(decrease) ->
    ...;
handle_message(_) ->
    %% Back to receiving loop
    handle_message().
```

You should prevent filling process mailbox.
In production-ready application, often nobody uses `receive` statement, often they use some standard codes which those codes handle receiving, timeouts, replies, hibernation, etc. we call those codes **behavior**, for example one of OTP standad behaviors is [gen_server behavior](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html)
Because OTP behaviors are for general purposes if you need very efficient code for doing some special duty, you have to write something named [**Special process**](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id79905) which should handle your own messages and Erlang system messages.

Comment: Thank you!  I was under the assumption the barebones of a gen_server was just a looped receive?  Also, how do you prevent filling the process mailbox?  As you can guess, the piece of code just increases/decreases the user connected.

Comment: Also, with the answer, I still get these messages!

Comment: Can you show the code ? Just sending messages to one process ?

Comment: I have around 10k+ processes sending to this 1 process.

Comment: @Pouriya Can you give a citation for, "You should always receive all messages from process mailbox and select what you want after getting."? By my thinking, that throws away an important ability: the ability to give priority to some messages over others via matching in the `receive` expression.

Comment: @RyanStewart I will give you some code example, if you did not understand why? make new question, [OTP/gen_fsm](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen_fsm.erl#L381), [OTP/gen_server](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen_server.erl#L380), [OTP/gen_statem](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen_statem.erl#L862)

Comment: I understand the gen_* processes do it this way. I'm wondering why you think that all code should do it that way. It's not a general question suitable for SO. I'm curious what your opinion is based on.

Comment: @RyanStewart    All codes haven't to receive all messages, for example when you make a gen_server:call, you are waiting for some special message [gen.erl Code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/gen.erl#L169), But in process's main code you should prevent filling process's mailbox by receiving all messages.